# Ctrl-V in TTY not escaping Ctrl-C

Tags: linux, bash, tty, escape-characters, escape-sequences

For the record, this has nothing to do with copying and pasting, which is likely why it's so difficult to find an answer.

I am attempting to insert a literal `CTRL-C` character into a stream from a TTY. In most cases, that means the character `0x03`. Normally, if you send `0x03` to a TTY, it will send an interrupt to the process (since it's the standard control code for INTR). However, I'd like to send that character to a running process **without entering raw mode**.

Normally, the `VLNEXT` character would be the solution (which is normally assigned to `CTRL-V` or `0x10`). For example, do this:

```sh
dd of=test bs=1 count=2
```

And then pressing `CTRL-V ESC ENTER` will result in a file that contains the sequence `0x1B 0x0A`. However, this is not working with `CTRL-C`. Doing the same thing and entering `CTRL-V CTRL-C` simply delivers the SIGINT to `dd`, and kills the program. According to the `VLNEXT` documentation in `termios(s)`, my understanding is that this prefix should work for *any* character with special meaning.

Excerpt from `termios(3)` on `VLNEXT`:

> ```
>   VLNEXT (not in POSIX; 026, SYN, Ctrl-V) Literal next (LNEXT).  Quotes the next input character, depriving
>          it of a possible special meaning.  Recognized when IEXTEN is set, and then not passed as input.
> ```

And lastly, my current `stty` settings (`iexten` enabled, and `lnext` set to `^V`):

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 51; columns 115; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab3 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

**EDIT**

I thought it was worth mentioning, the equivalent of what I'm trying to do with raw mode enabled would be running this:

```sh
stty raw -echo; dd of=test bs=1 count=1; stty sane
```

And then pressing `CTRL-C`. This results in a file containing just `0x03`. This is obviously a simplified example, but it's the type of thing I need to do. I can't enable raw mode prior to running the command (I need control sequences to still work), but I need to send raw data to the running command and escape it from being interpreted by the controlling TTY.

Comment: Works for me. I get as output from `od -c test` the 2 chars `003 \n`. I have the same `stty` output as you, bar the lines/columns. Done on a Fedora 25 in an xterm using bash and dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to circle back with an answer to my question. I was on the right track, but had the wrong byte value for `CTRL-V`. Technically, this is defined by the `VLNEXT` character in the termios settings. This character is normally `0x16` not `0x10` which does refer to `CTRL-V`. I likely read the value somewhere and misinterpreted it as decimal.

After prefixing my data with `0x16`, I can safely send control characters over an interactive TTY without triggering signals. It should be noted, though, that `0x16` is not standard, and can trivially be modified via `stty` or `termios` settings.